# Yet another <Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl'> error message

Tags: php, x86, openssl, easyphp-devserver

I'm using `EasyPhp DevServer` with `Apache 2.4.25`, `PHP 5.6.30`, and `PHP 7.1.3` installed.

For times, I usually switch between those two PHP versions, without changing any configuration element anywhere, and it works fine.

Now I just added `PHP 8.1.2`, and when I switch to it I get the well known error message:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php812vs16x86x230327010135\ext\php_openssl (Le module spécifié est introuvable), C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php812vs16x86x230327010135\ext\php_php_openssl.dll (Le module spécifié est introuvable)) in Unknown on line 0

Obviously I read a lot of answers about that, but no one seem to be of help in my case, since the `php.ini` for `8.1.2` includes the same needed specifications than the two other ones:

- `extension_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php812vs16x86x230327010135\ext"`, which is the correct path where resides `php_openssl.dll`
- `extension=openssl`, rather than `extension=php_openssl.dll` for the older versions (but the error message says it did search for `php_openssl.dll`)

Also, despite of what is said in `https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php`:

> Note to Win32 Users
> In order for this extension to work, there are DLL files that must be available to the Windows system PATH.
> (...)
> This extension requires the following files to be in the PATH: libeay32.dll, or, as of OpenSSL 1.1, libcrypto-*.dll

`openssl` is correctly loaded by `PHP 5.6.30` and `PHP 7.1.3` although nor the DLL nor other cited files are present in the Windows system PATH.

So I remain stuck: what else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

Looking for as many different advices as possible, I found a page from `RAD Studio`: `https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/OpenSSL`.
Only oriented to `openssl` itself for any purpose, it gives precise information about how to install it on Windows.

So I tried following its recommandation, which was to include a copy of the `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` dynamic library files to the file system, using the OpenSSL installer `https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html` to install `OpenSSL 1.1.1t Light`.
**And now `PHP 8.1.2` works fine with `openssl` enabled, and without any other change or addon!**

I can't figure out why these libraries are necessary for `PHP 8.1.2` when the older versions worked without them, especially since they are not exactly the ones cited by the PHP manual page `https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php`.